# How do I pass a string to a function requiring an Object?

Tags: c#, function, args, trello

I am using Chello (the c# wrapper for the Trello API). I need to pass the argument "createCard" as per the documentation here: https://trello.com/docs/api/card/index.html

And this is the function I am using from Chello:

```
public IEnumerable<CardUpdateAction> ForCard(string cardId, object args)
    {
        string queryString = BuildQueryString(args);

        return GetRequest<List<CardUpdateAction>>("/cards/{0}/actions?{1}", cardId, queryString);
    }
```

I have tried calling this in this way:

```
 List<CardUpdateAction> cua = chello.CardUpdates.ForCard("5264d37736695b2821001d7a","createCard").ToList();
```

but I get the error: **Parameter Count Mismatch**

on this function:

```
 protected static string BuildQueryString(object args)
    {
        string queryString = String.Empty;
        if (args != null)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var prop in args.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}&", prop.Name, prop.GetValue(args, null));
            }
            if (sb.Length > 0) sb.Remove(sb.Length - 1, 1);
            queryString = sb.ToString();
        }
        return queryString;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the fact that your API you are using expects you to pass in a class that has public properties equal to the tags you want to use.

This is very easy to do using [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx) (I am doing a slightly different example to help illustrate a point)

```
//This will cause BuildQueryString to return "actions=createCard&action_fields=data,type,date"
var options = new { actions = "createCard", action_fields = "data,type,date" };

List<CardUpdateAction> cua = chello.CardUpdates.ForCard("5264d37736695b2821001d7a",options).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

`string` is an `object`. Every type in .NET platform inherits from `Object`. This is called [**Unified Type System**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Unified_Type_System).

On the other hand, we have the [**Liskov Substitution Principle**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which put simply, says that if B is a subtype of A (B is A), then you should be able to use B, wherever A is used.

Based on these reasons, you can pass string to any method that accepts an object as an argument.

You can test it:

```
public void DoSomething(object args)
{
}

public void Main()
{
    DoSomething("some string argument, instead of the object");
}
```

It works just fine. No error.